# Checking if view is added on didSelectItem - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I'm hoping you can help me with my code. I'm trying to make it so that when a cell is clicked it checks if the view has already been added. If it has then it dismisses the view and re-adds it. If it doesn't then it simply adds the view.

Here's my current code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                        didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = NoteViewController()

    if self.view.subviews.contains(vc.view) {
        print("view removed")
    } 
    else {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AnnotatedPhotoCell
        sourceCell = cell
        vc.picture = resizeImage(image: cell.imageView.image!, 
                     targetSize: CGSize(width:(view.bounds.width - 45),height: 0))

        vc.comment = cell.commentLabel
        vc.parentVC = parentVC.self

        parentVC.self.addChildViewController(vc)
        parentVC.self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        // 3- Adjust bottomSheet frame and initial position.
        let height = view.frame.height
        let width  = view.frame.width

        vc.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:self.view.frame.maxY, 
                            width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Hoping you can help me with this.

Comment: So what *does* it do instead?

Comment: @NRitH it just adds the new vc. Because the vc declaration is at the top of the stack, every time the cell is clicked vc is given a new value and the code does not recognize that this new vc has been added so it adds it later in the stack. I've taken the vc declartion outside of the didselectitem method. Now when I click on another cell after having clicked on the first cell, the properties for the new cell (picture, comment. etc.) don't change from the first cell

Comment: You are creating a new view each time via ` let vc = NoteViewController()` so that specific view instance is never going to "already be there".  You should create an optional property in your cell subclass and only create the view if this property is nil.  If it isn't nil you can just update the existing view